# Codeigniter error if "no result found" or no "input was entered"; Else works fine

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am in the learning phase and trying to develop this search result app.
Everything works fine if results  were found but incase if there was no input or no result, it shows these 2 errors;

> Message: Undefined offset: 0
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object

This is where error happens search_model.php

```
function get_city_id_by_input($keyword){
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('vbc_city');
    $this->db->where('v_city_name', $keyword);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $query_result = $query->result();
    $row = $query_result[0];
    return $row->id;
}
```

And Controller:

```
$keyword = $this->input->post('search[1]');
$city_id = $this->search_model->get_city_id_by_input($keyword);
$data['results'] = $this->search_model->get_search_results($city_id);
$this->load->view('search', $data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

**In Model**

```
function get_city_id_by_input($keyword){
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('vbc_city');
    $this->db->where('v_city_name', $keyword);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $query_result = $query->result_array(); # Changed
    if (empty($query_result)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    elseif (count($query_result) > 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        $rowId = $query_result[0]['id']; # Changed
        return $rowId; # Changed    
    }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
$keyword = $this->input->post('search[1]');
if (empty($keyword)) {
    echo "Input is Empty";
}
else{
    $city_id = $this->search_model->get_city_id_by_input($keyword);
    $result = $this->search_model->get_search_results($city_id);
    if ($result == FALSE) {
        echo "No Data Found";
    }
    elseif ($result == 0) {
        echo "Multiple of records founds";
    }
    else{
        $data['results'] = $result
        $this->load->view('search', $data);
    }

}
```

Comment: * if there was no input or no result*

Comment: more like the truth  ^)

Comment: @splash58 added another one too ;)

Comment: @Abdulla, thanks so much... I didn't have to use the controller one though.. Model did it all

Comment: It worked just by the Model code you gave.. May be controller code was all set even before..

Comment: Beter you include that too. Happy to help